# How to display JSON in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, json, codeigniter

I am trying to display JSON data that I retrieve from an ajax call but I am unable to display any data.

This my function:

```
function runbiosis(){
  var url = site_url+"Biodata/runbiosis";
  $.getJSON(url,function(data) {
    $('#jk').val(data.jk);
    $('#agama').val(data.agama);
   });
};
```

JSON:

```
[{
    "jk": "Laki-Laki",
    "agama": "islam"
}]
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="jk" name="nama" required>
<input type="text" id="agama" name="nama" required>
```

How can I display this JSON in my HTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON data is an array with a single element but in your `runbiosis` function you are trying to access the property of an object, not an element of an array.

Can you try this - note it is the same code but you are getting the `jk` property of the first (and only) element of the array that is returned:

```
function runbiosis(){
  var url = site_url+"Biodata/runbiosis";
  $.getJSON(url,function(data) {
    $('#jk').val(data[0].jk);
    $('#agama').val(data[0].agama);
   });
};
```